# Rolling Deployments with ArgoCD ApplicationSets

Tags: argocd

I've been looking through the docs at https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user-guide/application-set/ and I still don't understand how I would go about doing rolling / partial deployments to multiple clusters.  I'm missing something.

How do I only deploy updates to clusters A, B, and C, and then later deploy to clusters X, Y, and Z?

Is there a sample app / YAMLs out there that explains how to do that?